# Which rounding mode to be used for currency manipulation in java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have read on java site to use `BigDecimal` for currencies.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

But what rounding mode we should use with? which is the most appropriate one and most widely us

Answer (score 54):

There is no "correct" mode, it depends on the business case. Examples:

- When calculating annual taxes, the fractions are often cut off (`RoundingMode.FLOOR`).
- When calculating a bonus, you might want to always round in favor of the customer (`RoundingMode.CEILING`).
- For taxes on a bill, you usually round `HALF_UP`
- When doing complex financial simulations, you don't want to round at all.

The [documentation of RoundingMode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) contains a lot of examples how the different modes work.

To get a better answer, you must tell us what you want to achieve.

That said, `BigDecimal` is the correct type to use in Java because it can preserve any amount of precision plus it lets you chose the rounding mode most suitable for your case.

Answer (score 21):

Most of the time `BigDecimal` is the only valid choice for currencies. But the choice of rounding strategy is not that obvious.

The default is [HALF_EVEN](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN) which happens to be a good choice. This algorithm is known as *bankers' rounding* (see discussion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding)).

Another common strategy is [HALF_UP](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP) which is more intuitive but has slightly worse statistical characteristics.

Also note that in many times (especially in banking and insurances) the rounding strategy will be dictated by business requirements, often different for various use-cases.

Comment: You should add that HALF_EVEN is inefficient.

Answer (score 13):

Typically you'd use "half up" rounding, like so:

```
myBigDecimal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

This way, you'll round to two decimal places (which most currencies use, e.g. dollars and cents, obviously there are exceptions), and you'll round values such that half a cent or more will round up while less than half a cent will round down. See [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP) for more details.

Answer (score 8):

For the financial applications ROUND_HALF_EVEN is the most common rounding mode. That mode avoids bias.
But for display you should use NumberFormat class. This class will take care of localization issues for amounts in different currencies. But NumberFormat accepts primitives only. So use last one if you can accept small accuracy change in transformations to a double.

Answer (score -10):

You should never use a decimal type for currencies. Use an integer type. This maintains accuracy buy avoiding rounding error associated with floats

When display an amount then divide by the appropriate factor to get the non-integral portion.

Comment: Actually, BigDecimals are perfectly safe and accurate if used correctly. Just don't use `double` or `float`.

Comment: +1: @aaamos except most investment banks use `double`, sometimes int/long. esp those using C/C++, it doesn't have a built in decimal type.

Comment: @Peter: another hint that they don't really know what they're doing. There are lot of currency/fixed point libraries for C++ and it's easy to write one yourself.

Comment: @Peter: this is clearly a Java question, not C/C++, and in Java, BigDecimal is the class created especially to avoid the inaccuracies of doubles and floats. Ahsan has correctly figured this out and telling him not to use decimal types does not answer his question, I'm afraid. Banks using doubles should be sued ;-)

Comment: Integers are useless when converting across currencies, especially when considering that exchange rates are expressed in decimals.

Comment: @aaamos, `double` is no more accurate in C/C++ than in Java, and yet C/C++ is used for financial applications. The assertion that you can't use `double` for money doesn't match how it is actually used in industry.

Comment: @VineetReynolds, exchanges rates can be represented as fixed point `int` values. Most high frequency FX trading systems use `int` or `long` values. I have worked on a couple and interviewed many developers in this space.

Comment: @Peter: Neither of the two financial institutions I've worked for used C for sensitive calculations (one used Java, one Smalltalk). Even those that do use C, I'm sure that when it comes to calculations where rates are specified to 8 decimal places and multiplied by millions of dollars, they make sure they don't just use doubles and hope no one notices the rounding errors (which would be quite significant at that level)...

Comment: @Peter, if you do not have to handle overflow in the result, you can represent exchange rates as integers or any primitive type. While this may be true of HFTs, this is not necessarily true for all accounting systems and in all scenarios. When dealing with  hyperinflationary currencies (like the Zimbabwe dollar),  BigDecimals are a better/only choice.

Comment: @VineetReynolds, This is true, however most financial institutions don't deal in hyper inflationary currencies.

Comment: @Peter, hyper inflation is just one example where one would see overflow in the result. Calculation of turnover and balances for accounts of several large companies, central banks, and lending institutions would be another place where using primitves would lead to overflow.

Comment: @VineetReynolds, Even in cases of hyper inflation, money needs to be understandable by humans as well as computers.  This puts an upper limit on the largest numbers a currency can have, otherwise no-one can understand them. In the most extreme causes, the upper limit is close to the limit of a `long` and if you need to be able to represent 32,776,899,763,734,490,417.05 Marks for example, you need BigDecimal.  However if you only need to represent the US national debt (which is only an estimate anyway) or a number smaller than this you can use `double` or `long`. e.g. 15,053,696,987,162.77

Comment: Is it ironic that the most informative part of this discussion is under the answer that has been down voted 5 times?